# Integrating Facebook iOS SDK with Comments using Connect

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, uiwebview

On an iOS application, I plan to host Facebook Comments using Facebook Connect within an UIWebView, have already done some tests and read articles where I think that it shall work fine.
My question regards authentication: I wanted to use Facebook iOS sdk to have and store the proper tokens within Objective C, so that the user doesn't have to do it every time. I know how to inject any data in the UIWebView if needed, but my question is WHAT do I need to inject so that the facebook scripts already see the user as authenticated every time ?
Thanks

Comment: This is just an idea but if user logs in using Safari ... doesn't he have the access in any WebView straight away?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm running into the same issue, and the answers below don't seem to address the question

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. You will get an access token when you authenticate the user which you can then use throughout your application to request information on the users behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest [Facebook iOS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/).

Create the Facebook object:

```
Facebook *myFacebook;
[self myMethodToDoSomeAuthenticatedStuffsWithAccessToken:myFacebook.accessToken];
```

Also, you can see the [sample "Hackbook" project](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook) to see how the access token is setup for the Facebook object within the application and how it is auto refreshed.

This keeps the user authenticated on the iOS Device and you can use this access token a NSString* type to do your stuffs.